# Using postgres arrays in Rails 4, how do I return an array of all the unique items in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

My migration looks like this:

```
create table :posts do |t|
    t.string :tags, array: true, default: []
end
```

How can I get an array of all the unique tags stored under tags in all posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could also do this:

```
Post.pluck(:tags).flatten.uniq
```

If you have a ton of posts this may be a fairly significant hit on performance though...

Comment: There's really no way around this as `Post.pluck(:tags).uniq` would return all the unique tag-sets. This is the down-side to using an array column instead of a many-to-many tag association table.

Comment: @tadman: There are ways around it, PostgreSQL has a fairly rich set of array [operators and functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html).

Answer (score 8):

You can do it inside the database with:

```
select distinct unnest(tags) from posts
```

So if you just want the strings then you can go straight to the database with:

```
tags = Post.connection.select_rows('select distinct unnest(tags) from posts').flatten
```

If there is a lot overlap amongst the `tags` arrays or a lot of arrays then that should be faster then pulling all the arrays out of the database and doing the data wrangling in Ruby.

Comment: I'd say this answer is better than my own.  I wasn't sure of the method to query on an array value in the database, but I was pretty sure it exists.  I might suggest trying to change the call slightly by doing something like `Post.select('DISTINCT unnest(tags) AS uniq_tags').pluck(:uniq_tags).flatten` -- `select_rows` seems like a bit of a hackish way of getting at it.

Comment: @nzifnab: You could wrap all the AR stuff around it if you wanted but I'm as comfortable with SQL as I am with Ruby and I find the usual "nothing but Ruby" attitude a bit puzzling; presumably you'd wrap this in a `Post` class method anyway. I don't think you'd need that `flatten` call, you need it with `select_rows` because it returns an AoA even if each row in the result set has only one entry.

Comment: Good point, don't need flatten.  And ya either way will get you the same result. I suppose it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted this, I found a working solution, although there may be a more elegant way of solving this:

```
Post.select(:tags).map(&:tags).flatten.uniq
```

I was being thrown off by the array of objects, solved by the .map.